# exposing Associated entities in ria services

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I have read this link :-

[RIA Services: Entity Framework Reference Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792737/ria-services-entity-framework-reference-entities)

and added `[Include]` in metadata class as well as in my domain service query.

On my client side i have a navigation property named `Photos` in my `Albums` entity. However it is of type EntityCollection and i don't know how to iterate over it. It has no get method and even indexing doesn't apply on it. I have tried the following :-

```
albums.photos[0]
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me how do i iterate over that photos collection in my albums entity ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the metadata for your Albums class you have something like:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute( typeof(Album.AlbumMetadata ) )]
public partial class Album
{
  internal sealed class AlbumMetadata
  {
    private AlbumMetadata ()
    { }

    [Include]
    public EntityCollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; } 
}
```

In your domain service you would have something like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Album> GetAlbums ()
    {
        var albums = from a in ObjectContext.Albums.Include( "Photos" )
                     orderby a.AlbumId descending
                     select a;
        return albums;
    }
```

In you clientside code you could then do:

```
public void LoadAlbumsWithPhotos ()
{
  LoadOperation<Album> albumLoader = Context.Load( Context.GetAlbumsQuery() );
  albumLoader.Completed += ( s, e ) =>
    {
       _albumStore = ( s as LoadOperation<Album> ).Entities.ToList();
    };
}
```

Photos could then be retrieved by:

```
var photos = _albumStore.First().Photos.Select( p => p);
```

Hope this helps.